# QPainter::drawImage() glitches in Qt 5.10

Tags: qt, qpainter

My application draws a 3D rendering to an offline `QImage` (without OpenGL for historical reasons) and then draws that `QImage` in a widget like this:

```
void Render3dModel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    // Update model and render new image
    m_model.calculate();
    QImage image = m_model.getImage();

    // Draw image in widget
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawImage(QPointF(0, 0), image);
}
```

The image gets repainted based on mouse movements using QWidget::update():

```
void Render3dModel::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    m_model.rotate(event);
    update();
}
```

This approach worked fast and flawless in Qt 5.6 and Qt 5.9. However, rebuilding the exact same code in Qt 5.10 results in strange glitches. Parts of two frames are visible at the same time. This is not a temporary effect (e.g. delayed drawing), because if I stop moving the mouse, it actually keeps showing parts two frames. Below is an example (using alternating gray and white backgrounds for even/odd frames for clarity):

[image: tearing]

I have tried creating deep copies using `image.copy()` in a `QImage` ringbuffer to see if this is some race-condition between destruction/reuse of the `QImage` and some deferred/delayed painting, but that does not help.

Apparently the mechanics of `QPainter` have changed between Qt 5.9 and Qt 5.10, but I am unable to find any clues in the documentation.

Please advice

**Update**

After playing with several window sizes, I came to the conclusion that the fault somehow corresponds to the same size rectangle aligned at the upper-left corner with the "S" of the "Section dimensions" label. However, as you can see in the screenshot, the frame with the white background has that part of the cone drawn at the correct position. So the image is not *shifted*, but *clipped* somehow?!

I have tried adding

```
painter.setClipping(false);
painter.setClipRect(QRect(0, 0, size().width(), size().height()));
```

but that has no effect. Does my `Render3dModel` occasionally get `paintEvent`'s from its parents?

**Update 2**

Adding a `mouseMoveEvent` handler to Kuba Ober's minimal example below, reproduces the problem on a MacBook (OS X 10.12.6, Intel HD Graphics 515):

[image: Reproduced glitch]

Could this perhaps be a regression in Qt 5.10 because I am unable to reproduce this in Qt 5.9? Should I file a bug report?

**Update 3**

This appears indeed to be regression in Qt 5.10 on OS X. Filed bug report https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-67998

Comment: No, the `Render3dModel` does not get paint events from its parents. If it does, then you've already corrupted the execution state of your process. Qt doesn't do such things.

Comment: I think I know what your problem may be: you're using a wrong size somewhere. Check that the image **and** `Render3dModel` have correct size!

Comment: It reproduces simply by issuing `update()` repeatedly, no need for mouse events. It is a Qt 5.10 regression indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be no race conditions in single-threaded code. There is no such thing as delayed/deferred painting. By the time `paintEvent` returns, the painting of that widget is done.

What you see is what you get. The `getImage()` method likely returns junk - perhaps an undersized image - and then you paint that junk. Replace `getImage()` with a simple alternating fill, and you'll see that it works fine:

[image: screenshot of the example code]

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/glitchy-paint-49930405
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <array>

class Render3dModel : public QWidget {
   struct Model {
      mutable int counter = {};
      QSize size;
      QFont font{"Helvetica", 48};
      QImage getImage() const {
         static auto const format = QPixmap{1,1}.toImage().format();
         QImage image{size, format};
         image.fill((counter & 1) ? Qt::blue : Qt::yellow);
         QPainter p(&image);
         p.setFont(font);
         p.setPen((counter & 1) ? Qt::yellow : Qt::blue);
         p.drawText(image.rect(), QString::number(counter));
         counter++;
         return image;
      }
   } m_model;
   void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override {
      m_model.size = size();
      auto image = m_model.getImage();
      QPainter{this}.drawImage(QPoint{0, 0}, image);
   }
};
```

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QWidget win;
   QVBoxLayout topLayout{&win};
   QTabWidget tabs;
   topLayout.addWidget(&tabs);
   // Tabs
   for (auto text : { "Shape", "Dimensions", "Layout"}) tabs.addTab(new QWidget, text);
   tabs.setCurrentIndex(1);
   QHBoxLayout tabLayout{tabs.currentWidget()};
   QGroupBox dims{"Section Dimensions"}, model{"3D Model"};
   QGridLayout dimsLayout{&dims}, modelLayout{&model};
   for (auto w : {&dims, &model}) tabLayout.addWidget(w);
   // Section Dimensions
   for (auto text : {"Diameter 1", "Diameter 2", "Length"}) {
      auto row = dimsLayout.rowCount();
      std::array<QWidget*, 3> widgets{{new QLabel{text}, new QDoubleSpinBox, new QLabel{"inch"}}};
      for (auto *w : widgets)
         dimsLayout.addWidget(w, row, dimsLayout.count() % widgets.size());
   }
   tabLayout.setAlignment(&dims, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
   dims.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Maximum);
   // Model
   Render3dModel render;
   modelLayout.addWidget(&render);
   model.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);
   model.setMinimumSize(250, 250);
   win.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, trying out your code gives both blue and yellow rectangles at the same time, similar to my example. So we can rule out m_model.getImage(). It really appears to be some problem with Qt or the way I am using it.

Comment: @JasonSmith Awesome. All I can tell you is that it works in a stand alone example. There's something else in your code that messes things up, perhaps writing over memory it shouldn't be writing over, etc. If you're using multithreading, remember that a given `QImage` instance can only be used from one thread at a time! It's valid to pass it from one thread to another, but only as a (shallow) copy.

Comment: Qt's implicit sharing is thread-safe, so as long as two threads operate on separate instance of a `QImage`, even if one was assigned from the other, it will work correctly. Any access must go through the `QImage` instance, though. If you held any pointers to bits in the image, you cannot operate on them if the image has copies taken of it. You'd have to detach, and thus deep copy, the second image, before passing it elsewhere. That's a common caveat of implicit sharing: the object itself must know of writes, and will block the first one until it can detach (deep copy if shared).

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate reply. Please add the mouseMoveEvent() handler to your minimal example, and you will see that the problem reproduces! I have updated my question with the corresponding screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the minimal example provided by @KubaOber, adding the *mouseMoveEvent()* handler as suggested by the OP, but I couldn't reproduce the issue on my platform (**Qt 5.10.1 - Linux**).

It looks to me it could be a **platform specific** issue. 
There are quite a few differences in the **cocoa** platform plugin between Qt 5.9 and Qt 5.10, in particular about **QCocoaBackingStore** and its flush() method ([changelog here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/commit/src/plugins/platforms/cocoa/qcocoabackingstore.mm?h=5.10&id=f25b4d2fe34413d575a06f0e39c779df4cf86e47)).

If the minimal, complete example shows well the issue I would suggest to report it to Qt's bug tracker at https://bugreports.qt.io.

Answer (score 0):

This is your bug:

```
void Render3dModel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    // Update model and render new image
    m_model.calculate();
    ...
}
```

You should not tie your model update to the paint event. The paint event is supposed to draw the current state of the model, and you may get multiple subsequent and/or partial paint events, when e.g. revealing parts of the window.

What you are seeing in your application is a partial expose event, which in this case is the result of a bug in Qt, but in general you may receive partial expose events and should be ready handle them.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. Unlike this minimal example, the real application does the model update in the `mouseMoveEvent`. But even if we update the minimal example by moving the `counter++` to the `mouseMoveEvent()` handler, the problem persists. So receiving multiple subsequent and/or partial events does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: Right, with the code fixed you are now hitting https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68023